How to Manage Controlled Updates to Clients with Limited Server Capacity
I am looking for the best way to manage controlled updates to my clients, ensuring that I can test and verify updates before releasing them.
Here’s the scenario:

I have a test machine that is identical to my client machines.
Before pushing updates to clients, I want to test and verify the updates on my test machine to ensure stability.
I don’t have enough server space or capacity to host a full repository. However, I can host a smaller repository containing only the verified packages.

My goal is to test packages on the test machine first, then release the updates to the client machines in a controlled manner after verification. What would be the best way to implement this kind of package management workflow on Ubuntu?
Would creating a custom repository for just the verified packages be the best approach? If so, how can I ensure the test machine gets the latest updates, while clients only receive verified ones? Also how in practice would I go about saving all of the test-machines verified packages as .deb files?
Any other approaches that might suit this limited server capacity setup?
